# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Movies & TV's [second moderator election](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: A J]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking Ankit Sharma, who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5124918786129920/0).

Comment: Holy hell, I came second?! :-O Was expecting to be fourth or fifth at best.

Comment: Congratulations AJ! First choice from me :)

Answer (score 10):

**Congratulations AJ .... well done.**

And commiserations to everyone else who took part.  Thank you all for volunteering.  There was a great field of candidates.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you all for your kind words. :)

And thank you Ankit Sharma. You've been a great moderator and friend. Nobody can fill your shoes (I can try but no one will). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot and I can surely count on you to carry it forward.

Comment: I appreciate your great enthusiasm!

Answer (score 6):

### **Congratulations AJ!**

It was always pretty clear that you'd win, but it took more rounds than I expected before you crossed the threshold to be elected. Enjoy the double diamond, moderate the site with calmness and efficiency, and **may the modds be ever in your favour!**

Comment: You came in second, because you're an awesome mod, silly bean :)

Answer (score 6):

### Congratulations AJ!

I expected you would win, but I appreciate everyone that considered me as well. Mods on our site have been pretty awesome and I'm sure you'll fit right in!

Answer (score 6):

AJ is the new moderator on Movies & TV,

I'm just sad it wasn't me.

As I look at the results it wasn't much of a fight,

but I see things in a positive light.

The site has a wonderful new addition to its team,

and with pride it should beam.

---

**Congratulations AJ!**

And thank you all you did cast a vote for me, it is very humbling to earn your respect.

Answer (score 5):

**Congratulations AJ!!**

[image]

Enjoy the double diamond. (Don't forget to change parent site to Movies & TV again ;-))

---

> [image: Ankit Sharma with a diamond]

I will really miss the diamond beside your name Ankit Sharma. You have been a great moderator and friendly to everyone. Your name appears strange in black. I hope you will be back in blue soon.

Thank you to everyone who voted for me. It has been a great experience.

Comment: Thanks for the nice words.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats to AJ! Well deserved :o)

Answer (score 4):

Congrats, AJ!

And I am sincerely humbled to have come in 3rd.  Thank you, everyone who considered me!

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations AJ.

+1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Congrats AJ!!

Well deserved and I knew you'd be the first choice. Wish you all the best and lets make MTV SE even better than how it is.

Looking at the results, can't believe I came in 4th ;) . I thought I'll be the last for sure.

Thank you everyone who voted for me. It's a great honor to earn your respect and trust that I could be a good mod.

Thank You Ankit Sharma for everything you did. Happy retirement "old" bud ;)

Comment: @AJ See what I was saying? when I first joined , everywhere I go, there was almost all of'em got this. edited by AJ ;)